# C# object reference question

Tags: c#

I am creating a really basic program, that has a method to fill an array but I am getting an error I don't understand. I am a Java programmer trying to acclimate to C# and .NET. Any help would be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestThreads
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             int[]  empty = new int[50001];
             int[] filled = new int[50001];

            filled = compute(empty); //error occurs here

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public int[] compute(int[] inArray)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inArray.Length; i++)
            {
                inArray[i] = i << 2;
            }

            return inArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

Error   1   **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property** 'TestThreads.Program.compute(int[])'  C:\Users\hunter.mcmillen\Desktop\TestProcessSplitting\TestProcessSplitting\Program.cs   17  22  TestThreads

Thanks,
Hunter

Comment: Java would give you a similar error in that case... you're trying to call an instance method as if it was static.

Comment: correct, but the Java compiler gives me this message: non-static method compute(int[]) cannot be referenced from a static context, which I can actually understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compute method should be static.

```
public static int[] compute(int[] inArray)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to call `compute` which is an instance method from `Main` which is a `static` method.  To fix this make `compute` static as well`

```
public static int[] compute(int[] inArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Main` is a static method - it is not specific to any single object - indeed, no instance of `Program` is created to call `Main`. `compute` is an instance method, and needs to be invoked on a single object.

Two options:

1. make `compute` static, which makes sense since it uses no state (fields):

   ```
   public static int[] compute(int[] inArray) {...}
   ```
2. create an instance in `Main`:

   ```
   var obj = new Program();
   filled = obj.compute(empty);
   ```

The first is more appealing here. I've included the second purely for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Change  `public int[] compute(int[] inArray){...}`

to

`public static int[] compute(int[] inArray){..}`

or change your call from

```
filled = compute(empty);
```

to

```
filled = new Program().compute(empty);
```

The `compute()` method that you have is an instance (non-static) method and requires an instance to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Add static to the compute method declaration.

```
public static int[] compute(int[] inArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're method is not static, but is being referenced from a static method. Change it to static. Solved.

```
public static int[] compute(int[] inArray) { ... }
```